# how to block website from loading in iframe?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iframe, youtube

Recently i tried to load youtube website in an iframe, but i checked that it's not worked. i used this simple code.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title></title>
</head>
<body>
<iframe width="1000px" height="700px" src="http://www.youtube.com" ></iframe>
</body>
</html>
```

1. i want to know , why my webpage can't load youtube website in
   iframe..
2. what code i use to load the youtube website in my webpage.
3. how i use same techniq in my website, so no one can add my website
   in iframe.

Answer (score 48, accepted):

**This answer was written in 2013 and documents a DEPRECATED header. See other answers for a modern equivalent.**

---

For browsers of 2013, a `X-Frame-Options` HTTP header needs to be used. It can be implemented through web server configuration settings.

You can view the `X-Frame-Options` in Header as in the image below,
[image]

Reference: https://www.keycdn.com/blog/x-frame-options/

If your browser does not support it, then you will have NO clickjacking defense in place and can use HTTP Header Field X-Frame-Options,

```
  <meta http-equiv="X-Frame-Options" content="deny">
```

There are three possible values for X-Frame-Options:

DENY -
The page cannot be displayed in a frame, regardless of the site attempting to do so.

SAMEORIGIN -
The page can only be displayed in a frame on the same origin as the page itself.

ALLOW-FROM uri -
The page can only be displayed in a frame on the specified origin.

Comment: so there's no way to use the webpage in iframe, because i saw some site and software.. who use embed youtube webpage , so if they can use youtube type bigwebsite.. so may be there is hole in this techniq.. or is this perfect.. ?

Comment: Note: As of April 2016 this meta tag no longer works in most browsers. RFC 7034 recommends this meta tag be ignored: https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7034#section-4 . Most major browsers removed support accordingly. See https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=156625

Comment: To clarify, the HTML meta tag is indeed useless now (see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/X-Frame-Options#Examples), but the `X-Frame-Options` HTTP header still applies and is the correct way to do it.

Answer (score 26):

As of April 2016 the accepted answer by [Krish R](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2919798/krish-r) no longer works.  [Most browsers](https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=156625) now ignore the meta tag as recommended by [RFC 7034](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7034#section-4).

The correct way to implement this header is to have it sent with the document by the server. See the mozilla documentation on [X-Frame-Options](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/X-Frame-Options) for details.