# How do you block your site from iframes?

Tags: html, iframe

I've been wondering. A while ago, I was messing with `I-Frames` when I discover that some websites could not be displayed within `I-Frames`. So? How do you do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Duplicate?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19843085/how-to-block-website-from-loading-in-iframe)

You can use `HTTP Header Field X-Frame-Options`:

`<meta http-equiv="X-Frame-Options" content="deny">`