# chrome extension get source html not currentPage

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, request

How can I get source https://google.com when I'm in http://example.com in chrome extension.
I read: [Getting the source HTML of the current page from chrome extension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11684454/getting-the-source-html-of-the-current-page-from-chrome-extension) but it get html currentPage only. 
I need get html source from any url.
Thanks!

Comment: Im sorry but I dont get the question

Comment: How can I get source from other page, not currentPage like example I gave?

Comment: You mean getting the source of a tab from another tab?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Use [XMLHttpRequest](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest) to download whatever the server responds with when the url is accessed. On some sites it could be a minipage with script loader that would later render the page in case it were loaded by the browser normally.
- To get a fully rendered source or DOM tree of an arbitrary url you'll have to load it in a tab first. To make the process less distracting for the user load it in a pinned tab:

  ```
  chrome.tabs.create({url: "https://google.com", pinned: true}, function(tab) {
      .... wait for the tab to load, get the source
  });
  ```

  (the simplest form of waiting that doesn't require any additional permissions would be periodic checking of `tab.status == "complete"` invoked from the above callback, otherwise use [webNavigation.onCompleted](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/webNavigation#event-onCompleted) for example or inject a [content script](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts) with the run-of-the-mill "DOMContentLoaded" or "load" event handlers).
- Or load the page in an `IFRAME` but some sites [forbid](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19843216/3959875) the browser to do it.

Comment: It's work. this is my function for who need it.
function loadHTMLSource(urlSource){
  xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhttp.open("GET", urlSource, false);
  xhttp.send();
  return xhttp.response;
}}