# Use javascript to get domain name including subdomains

Tags: javascript, subdomain

I just wanted to know if there was a way to get something to be future proof, as we may create new subdomains, and want people know that the site they are using is correct (as we have had a few cases of people rehosting our site)

```
if(window.location.href != "example.com" || "*.example.com"){
document.getElementById('alert').innerHTML = "This is site is not recognized as an official site";}
```

Where "*" would be a wildcard for any subdomain, and the ID "alert" is a div which we use to display important message.

Comment: Use `location.hostname` and check it with a regex but this test seems useless: either you're providing the page or the user may change the script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `location.hostname` and check if it ends with your domain, e.g. like this:

```
if(!location.hostname.match(/example.com$/)){
     alert(...);
}
```

This will match the domain *example.com* as well as *www.example.com* and any *subdomain.example.com*. But it will also match things like *otherexample.com*. To prevent this, use the following regex:

```
if(!location.hostname.match(/(^|\.)example.com$/)){
     alert(...);
}
```

This regex matches anything which is only *example.com* or starts with a dot and ends with *example.com*, so *www.example.com* and *subdomain.example.com*, but not *otherexample.com* because there's not dot in front of this *example.com*.

Answer (score 0):

I would rather look into using the meta header X-Frame-Options and Content-Security-Policys to solve your problem of rehosting.

X-Frame-Options: https://stackoverflow.com/a/19843216/634264

Content-Security-Policys: http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/security/content-security-policy/