# Ionic - Display a website within a div/frame

Tags: javascript, html, cordova, ionic-framework, ionic-view

I have used iframe to display my website, everything works great till i click on the place order button and everything freeze. I get a message from the payment gateway that they do not support iframe.

I tried to use < object> also < embed> nothing works. Is there any way I can display the website on Ionic? I am using my own header title and tabs at the bottom at the moment contents loads in the mid section.

I will really appreciate any help.

Thanks.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/19843216/602066 - Check that.

Comment: i tried this     <meta http-equiv="X-Frame-Options" content="sameorigin"> and it still doesnt work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You talked about payment gateway so I guess you're talking about a page with very sensitive information.
For security reasons, these pages that should be safe have their `http-equiv "X-Frame-Options"` set to `deny`.
It's easy for a page to get info from a page in an inner iframe, that's why it's really dangerous to put a page like payment and things like that in an iframe of another website

Comment: It is a wordpress website with wocommerce plugin. I am just embedding a the link and everything else loads from the web.